# Running the packaged tests while installing with sfdx:force:package:install

Tags: unit-test, managed-package, salesforcedx, package-install, unlocked-package

Is there a way to run packaged or org tests when we install a Managed/Unlocked SFDX package to an org using `sfdx force:package:install`?

Comment: I asked Dileep about this, specifically in the context of rolling back the installation on failure. He said it was a good idea and they would look at implementing it. So, not possible today

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far you can't. The only thing you can run is Apex Classes compilation with the `--apexcompile` flag.

However, starting Winter 21, code coverage should be enforced for Unlocked Packages installation.

The original post from PM Dileep Burki is available [here](https://success.salesforce.com/0D53A00004qE3RF), feel free to go there and give your thoughts about it.

> **Enforcement of Code Coverage in Unlocked Packages**
>   One of the issues many of you have raised in the past is a lack of enforcement of code coverage when it comes to Unlocked Packages. We all know the value of well-written tests when we package Apex. Starting Winter ’21, we want to enforce 75% code coverage. You will be able to create unlocked package versions even if code coverage is less than 75%, but such package versions can only be installed in scratch orgs and non-production orgs. In order to promote a package version from beta to released, you will have to have a minimum of 75% code coverage. You can choose to run code coverage during package version creation by supplying the optional --codecoverage parameter. Starting Summer ’20, in the CLI, we will show a warning that this change is coming. We believe a 4+ month notification is sufficient for you to get prepared for this change. Please let us know your thoughts and comments.

Comment: Is this consistent with Org-dependent packages?

Comment: This doesn't apply to org-dependent package, as stated in the doc: "We don’t calculate code coverage for org-dependent unlocked packages" https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_unlocked_pkg_code_coverage.htm